# Makefile - export declarations to sub-makefiles

Tags: makefile

I know variables can be exported to sub-makefiles: [Communicating Variables to a Sub-make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Variables_002fRecursion.html)

Example:

- Makefile:

  ```
  export PWD := $(shell pwd)

  target:
          @echo $(PWD)
          @cd somewhere; $(MAKE)
  ```
- somewhere/Makefile

  ```
  target:
          @echo $(PWD)
  ```

Supposing that the first Makefile is located at `/path/to/first/makefile`, the code above will print:

```
/path/to/first/makefile
/path/to/first/makefile
```

My question is: is there a way to let the variable PWD be **implicitly** evaluated inside sub-makefiles?
The output should look like this:

```
/path/to/first/makefile
/path/to/first/makefile/somewhere
```

So far I can only think of:

- Exporting the literal declaration and use the function `eval`
- Do it somehow with `.SECONDEXPANSION`
- Put the declaration into a separate file and include it
  in both the first and the second Makefile

All this solution are explicits: they imply code to be added to the sub-makefiles. 
What I'm searching is an implicit solution which will change only the code inside the first Makefile.

Plus, honestly...the first two solutions are so ugly I would rather declare manually PWD in every sub-makefile.

[EDIT]

Just to make it more clear: the variable PWD is just an example, I'm not trying to obtain the path of every Makefile.

Comment: Which version of Make are you using? These makefiles work as you intend in GNUMake 3.8.1.

Comment: I'm using GNU Make 3.81

Comment: I don't think it is possible. For environment variables it is always like if they are assigned with `:=` and not with `=`

Answer (score 0):

Use `${MAKEFILE_LIST}` variable and let make change directories for you:

```
[max@earth:~/tmp]$ cat Makefile
target:
    @echo $(abspath $(lastword ${MAKEFILE_LIST}))
    ${MAKE} -C somewhere $@

[max@earth:~/tmp]$ cat somewhere/Makefile 
target:
    @echo $(abspath $(lastword ${MAKEFILE_LIST}))

[max@earth:~/tmp]$ make target
/home/max/tmp/Makefile
make -C somewhere target
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/max/tmp/somewhere'
/home/max/tmp/somewhere/Makefile
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/max/tmp/somewhere'
```

That prints the full path to the makefile being processed. Use `$(dir $(abspath $(lastword ${MAKEFILE_LIST})))` to chop off filename `Makefile`.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question for two reasons: 1) PWD is just an example, what I'm trying to achieve is the auto-expansion of an exported variable, not obtaining the value of the current directory at every makefile (i will edit my question in order to make it more clear). 2) The solution you are proposing will imply changing the code inside each sub-makefile and that's exactly what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: @TKK I did not understand your question then.